# maven process-resources not replacing the place holder in property file on Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven

I am facing an issue with the mvn process-resources.
The resources are not getting processed on Linux where as same is working on the Windown machine.
Can some one help on this? Below are the configuration

Pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <superpom-basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</superpom-basedir>

        <!-- Omega -->
        <project.version>${project.version}</project.version>
        <reins-core.version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</reins-core.version>

        <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>

        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <oro.version>2.0.8</oro.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.4</lombok.version>
        <hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-validator.version>1.4.0</commons-validator.version>
        <commons-collections.version>3.2.1</commons-collections.version>
        <commons-logging.version>1.1.1</commons-logging.version>
        <commons-fileupload.version>1.2.2</commons-fileupload.version>

        <!-- Email -->
        <javax-mail.version>1.4.5</javax-mail.version>
        <xmlworker.version>5.4.1</xmlworker.version>

        <jbpm-bpmn2.version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</jbpm-bpmn2.version>
        <jbpm-bpmn2.patch.version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</jbpm-bpmn2.patch.version>
        <kie.version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</kie.version>
        <drools-persistence-jpa.version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</drools-persistence-jpa.version>
        <drools.version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</drools.version>
        <drools.patch.version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</drools.patch.version>

        <aspectj.version>1.6.11</aspectj.version>
        <jsoup.version>1.6.1</jsoup.version>

        <omega2.version>2.clmptf.40</omega2.version>

    </properties>

    <!-- ===== -->
    <!-- Build -->
    <!-- ===== -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                </plugin>

                <!-- PMD & checkstyles configuration -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources> 
            <resource>
                <directory>src\main\resources\config</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                  <includes>
                    <include>config.properties</include>
                  </includes>
                <targetPath>\config</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src\main\resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>             
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Property File

```
#Version
version=${omega.version}
```

The value of ${omega.version} is not getting replaced.
Can some one please help me ?

Regards
Gaurav

Comment: Don't use backslashes in the pom file. don't use maven-eclipse-plugin anymore cause it's outdated.  The maven-war-plugin you have defined is an ancient version....Take a look for the uptodate version here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: Ok, but does it make differance between windows and linux ? It is working on Windows but not on Linux.

Comment: Even after removing backslashes it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

`<filtering>false</filtering>`

Change value to `true`

Comment: Is you see I just want to filter the files under config folder So I have added  <resource>
                <directory>src\main\resources\config</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                  <includes>
                    <include>config.properties</include>
                  </includes>
                <targetPath>\config</targetPath>
            </resource> and as I dont want other to get filtered I have used false for other files.